# Where is FloatField?

Tags: lucene.net

I've added Lucene.Net to a .Net 6 Core project and indexing docs with TextField, StringFiled, and Int32Field all work fine but FloatField doesn't seem to be supported.  I'm using LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48. According to https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FloatField.html, FloatField has been available since version 4.1 of Java Lucene.  What am I missing? Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Lucene.NET 4.8.0 migration guide](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/core/migration-guide.html#net-api-conventions). Numeric types and method names including numeric types have been changed to use .NET conventions.

> Instead of Float use Single. Note that Lucene.Net.Queries.Function.ValueSources.SingleFunction was renamed Lucene.Net.Queries.Function.ValueSources.SingularFunction to distinguish it from the System.Single data type.

So, `FloatField` has been renamed to [`SingleField`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/core/Lucene.Net.Documents.SingleField.html).

Comment: Awesome. The migration guide has answered several of my questions. Thank you.